# How to group objects, But only make into a Single big "Mesh"

Tags: armature

I would like to know how to group my Limb pieces all together
yet have all individual parts still move with their correct bones; something like [this](http://darkknightpl.deviantart.com/art/EverythingAnimations-FNaF-1-Models-for-Blender-568267642).

If you select the model, there is one big group, but the individual objects can still be moved.

I would like to know how this can be accomplished. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this:

1. Select one of the objects (mesh)
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right mouse click</kbd> to select the rest of the objects
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them all into one big mesh
4. List the big mesh then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right click</kbd> on the armature
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent the mesh to the armature
6. Select Automatic Weighting

Comment: When i parent the Mesh to the Armature it says "Make parent without inverse" and when i press that it shrinks the mesh but not the Armature

Comment: @AGuestQuestioner Could you please upload the .blend file so I can check that?

Comment: I Fixed that, But this deforms my mesh. I Don't want that. It should be like how it would be moving individual peices like normal without grouping.

Comment: @AGuestQuestioner could you provide a .blend file to be able to help you? I can't understand or get what you mean

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: @AGuestQuestioner blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com